# GetSet nested property

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp

Having trouble accessing a response back from a rest API service that has nested property.

For example here's the raw REST response:

```
"count": 5,
"results": [
    {
      "suggestion": "1 Wonston Road, Southampton, SO16 ...",
      "matched": [[ 29, 37 ]],
  {
      "suggestion": "3 Wonston Road, Southampton, SO16 ...",
      "matched": [[ 29, 37 ]],
```

Suggestion and Match are nested property within results. 
The function that gets the response in my code is
`IRestResponse<SearchResponse> response = client.Execute<SearchResponse>(request);` I've used rest sharp here and the call is actually accurate as I get all the data back in form of a raw response.

I've defined the SearchResponse class as

```
//same for result, match, suggestion. 
private string _count;
public string Count
{
    get
    {
        return _count;
    }

    set
    {
        _count = value;
    }
}
```

How can I define nested variables to pass them into `SearchResponse.suggestion`? Currently the nested properties are stored in results.

Comment: It's really unclear what exactly you're asking, but simply generate a proper class representing the JSON structure. You can do so at http://json2csharp.com.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class Result {
     public string suggestion { get; set; }
     public List<List<int>> matched { get; set; }
     public string format { get; set; } }

 public class RootObject {
     public int count { get; set; }
     public List<Result> results { get; set; } }
```

http://json2csharp.com Did the trick, Thank you